# pandas groupby aggregate column name based on value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to do a Pandas Groupby that counts the distinct value of the group by column and then uses that name to create a NamedAgg column with that name.  For example:

```
animals = pd.DataFrame({'kind': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog'],'color': ['red', 'black', 'red', 'yellow']})
animals

kind.     color
cat.      red
dog.      black
cat.      red
dog.      yellow
```

I tried using this code:

```
animals.groupby('kind').agg(
red=(animals['color']=='red', 'count'),
black=(animals['color']=='black', 'count'),
yellow=(animals['color']=='yellow', 'count'))
```

I wanted to get this result:

```
kind.     red.      black.      yellow
cat.       2
dog.                  1.         1
```

I researched and tried everything

Comment: Use `animals.pivot_table(index='kind', columns='color', aggfunc='size')`

Comment: Or `animals.groupby(['kind', 'color']).size().unstack()`

Comment: Thank you.  I can't tell you how frustrated I am because I send hours trying to find the solution myself and it literally took you 30 seconds to answer this.  :)